# How can I determine if a string is a local folder string or a network string?

Tags: c#, unc

How can I determine in c# if a string is a local folder string or a network string besides regular expression?

For example:

I have a string which can be `"c:\a"` or `"\\foldera\folderb"`

Comment: Even a UNC path (starting with `\\\`) can be pointing to your local machine.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520753/what-is-the-correct-way-to-check-if-a-path-is-an-unc-path-or-a-local-path/520796#520796

Comment: It is too late but this is perfect answer 
[link], hope this some one


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243569/check-if-path-is-on-network#2244497

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method to determine if path string is local or remote machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354477/method-to-determine-if-path-string-is-local-or-remote-machine)

Answer (score 30):

I think the full answer to this question is to include usage of the DriveInfo.DriveType property.

```
public static bool IsNetworkPath(string path)
{
    if (!path.StartsWith(@"/") && !path.StartsWith(@"\"))
    {
        string rootPath = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(path); // get drive's letter
        System.IO.DriveInfo driveInfo = new System.IO.DriveInfo(rootPath); // get info about the drive
        return driveInfo.DriveType == DriveType.Network; // return true if a network drive
    }

    return true; // is a UNC path
}
```

Test the path to see if it begins with a slash char and if it does then it is a UNC path.  In this case you will have to assume that it is a network path - in reality it may not be a path that points at a different PC as it could in theory be a UNC path that points to your local machine, but this isn't likely for most people I guess, but you could add checks for this condition if you wanted a more bullet-proof solution.

If the path does not begin with a slash char then use the DriveInfo.DriveType property to determine if it is a network drive or not.

Comment: Isn't this wrong for rooted paths like '/tmp/file.txt', even though it's not specified in the examples above?

Answer (score 23):

`new Uri(mypath).IsUnc`

Comment: There's also IsFile to determine the opposite

Comment: Notice: this solution is not aware of network drives

Answer (score 7):

See this answer to get the DriveInfo object for a file path

[C# DriveInfo FileInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370267/c-driveinfo-fileinfo)

Use the DriveType from this to determine if it is a network path.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx

Comment: The `DriveInfo` won't work with netowrk paths like `\\foldera\folderb` throwing an `ArgumentException'

Answer (score 1):

One more way to check whether path point to local or network drive:

```
var host = new Uri(@"\\foldera\folderb").Host; //returns "foldera"
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(host))
{
   //Network drive
}
```

Comment: This won't work with a mapped network driver. It still returns an empty host