# Enumerate directories that match wildcard

Tags: c#, regex

This is my folder structure:

```
c:\logs\v1\api1
c:\logs\v1\api2
c:\logs\v2\api1
c:\logs\v2\api2
c:\logs\other
```

I would like to get all folders that match this pattern:

```
c:\logs\v*\api*
```

So, what I want is to get list of theese:

```
c:\logs\v1\api1
c:\logs\v1\api2
c:\logs\v2\api1
c:\logs\v2\api2
```

This doesn't work:

```cs
var result = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\logs\v*\api*");
```

Because `System.IO.IOException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'c:\logs\v*\api*''` is thrown

This doesn't work:

```cs
var directory = @"c:\logs\v*\api*";
var rootDirectory = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(directory);
var remainingPath = directory.Substring(rootDirectory.Length);
Console.WriteLine($"remainingPath: {remainingPath}");

var result = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory, remainingPath);
```

Because `System.IO.IOException: 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'c:\logs\v*''` is thrown

This works:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> ResolveDirectories(string path)
{
    if (path.Contains("*") || path.Contains("?"))
    {
        var parts = new Regex(@"[\\/](?=[^\\/]*[\*?])").Split(path, 2);
        var searchRoot = parts[0];
        var searchPatterns = parts[1].Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
        foreach (var dir in ResolveWildcards(searchRoot, searchPatterns))
            yield return dir;
    }
    else
    {
        yield return path;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> ResolveWildcards(string searchRoot, string[] searchPatterns)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(searchRoot))
    {
        // use next pattern to search in a search root
        var next = searchPatterns[0];
        // leave the rest for recursion
        var rest = searchPatterns.Skip(1).ToArray();

        if (!searchRoot.EndsWith("\\"))
            searchRoot += "\\";

        foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(searchRoot, next))
        {
            // if nothing left (last pattern) - return it
            if (rest.Length == 0)
                yield return dir;
            else
            {
                // otherwise search with rest patterns in freshly found directory
                foreach (var sub in ResolveWildcards(dir, rest))
                    yield return sub;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't like how this is coded.

Thanks to @Alessandro_D'Andria I created this:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> ResolveDirectories(string path)
{
    var parts = new Regex(@"[\\/](?=[^\\/]*[\*?])").Split(path, 2);
    var root = parts[0];
    var part = @".*\\" + parts[1].Replace(@"\", @"\\");

    var regex = new Regex(part);
    var dirs = Directory
            .EnumerateDirectories(
                root,
                "*",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x))
            .ToList();

    return dirs;
}
```

But both solutions are big mess. Is there any more elegant solution?

Comment: @hamaronooo It would work with: `Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "di*")`, but not with `Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "di*\v*")`

Comment: @hamaronooo link you've sent is not helping at all

Comment: Maybe `var result = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"c:\logs\v*").SelectMany(folderPath => Directory.EnumerateDirectories(Path.Combine(folderPath, "api*"))).ToArray();`.

Comment: @John what if there was `\v*\api*\office*`? I would like to have a flexible solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating, just using some regex and linq should be enough:

```
var regex = new Regex(@".*\\logs\\v\d+\\api\d+");
var dirs = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(
        @"C:\logs",
        "*",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x));
```

Comment: I don't think this is efficient. In my case, there would be enumerated whole `c:` directory with all subdirectories.

Comment: @dafie why the whole `c:` directory, you can start from `logs`.

Comment: I tested this in benchmark, and this is about 900 times slower than my solution. But anyway - I like your approach. Would it be possible to have this like a method to which you just pass a path (like in my solution)?

Comment: I updated question with code based on your solution